# i keep getting "Parameter 'speaker' unfilled" and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: python-3.x, warnings, chatbot

i keep getting "Parameter 'speaker' unfilled :31" and im not sure how to fix it

[code from thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77ZlE.png)

the solution i tried was to assign a default value to the 'speaker' parameter in the 'handle_click()' function definition

Comment: nevermind i fixed it idk how i fixed it but i did